# Get value from div in a html string with jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem when i try to grab the value from a div in my html string. Maybe someone here could find the problem for me.

I have tried a lot of different ways to take the data out. Solutions that works for others don't work for me at all. So i think i am doing something seriously wrong

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = 1;

    function updateMsg() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/opt/history/update?current=" + 1,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                id = $(html).find('#last').html();
                console.log('ID: ' + id);
                $("#result").html(html);
            }
        });
        setTimeout(updateMsg, 5000);
    }

    updateMsg();
});
```

This is how the div looks like

```
<div id="last" style="display: none;">2</div>
```

There is a bunch of html code before this div. This div will always be at the bottom of the html string.

**Update:** The thing is. I need to transport the value of a id in this html string but not show it visually. If you have a better way that i should look at.

The HTML output on success

```
<tr>
<td>2014-07-08 14:35:47.456</td>
<td>123</td><td>321</td>
<td>Has data</td>
<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-request="2014-07-08 14:35:47.456" data-mobile="123" data-check="321" data-log="Has latest update" data-context="Context" data-historyid="28" title="info" class="open-logInfo btn btn-default" href="#logInfo">
<i class="icon-info-sign icon-black"></i> Info </a>
</td>
</tr>
<div id="last" style="display: none;">28</div>
```

Comment: `I have a problem when i try to grab the value from a div in my html string.`What's the problem?

Comment: When i try to console.log the id value. It is empty or undefined on everything i have tried

Comment: Can you give us the out put of `console.log( html )` in the success callback.

Comment: Did you evaluate your "html" in success function. Your code looks correct I think maybe you get wrong result?

Comment: Please let me know why you are appening +1 in url ("/opt/history/update?current=" + 1)

Comment: And one more question, are you really need to return a html string from server side? Didn't you have an opportunity to return Json

Comment: I could return Json. But what i want to do is to add more rows for my table. The server creates the rows and sends them back as html. But i need the last id for the last row. Thats why i try to send a hidden div with that value

Comment: I think i get correct html code since it can add to the rows of the table. But i could try to get the output

Comment: Can you please show for us your html? I understand that it's correct but we need to see a structure, to find issue

Comment: The raw html output is edited into the post

Comment: To answer why i append  + 1. It is to test the query. But it will be replaced by the id as soon as i can take it out from the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter()` for it

```
 success: function(html){
                id = $(html).filter('#last').html();
                console.log('ID: ' + id);
                $("#result").html(html);
           }
```

`find()` will always search for the child elements.

**Edit**

Your returned html is invalid. Because the div is outside the `tr`. Thats why your code is returning undefined. Either you have to include that div inside a `td`(then you have to use `find()` ).

[**Fiddle using find()**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/284/)

Or you need to wrap the `tr` with a `table`. In this case you can use `filter()`

[**Fiddle using filter()**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/285/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding ('#last'), you can directly access it

```
id = $('#last').html();
```

Comment: No he cant, the HTML is not included to the DOM

Comment: This will look in the DOM, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to insert this HTML into DOM, then only you can use jQuery to search your #last div with it. for eg.

```
function updateMsg() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "/opt/history/update?current=" + 1,
       cache: false,
       success: function(html){
            $("#result").html(html);
            id = $("#result #last").text();
            console.log('ID: ' + id);
       }
    });
setTimeout(updateMsg, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Adding it to the HTML is a bad idea. It is polluting the DOM and take extra juice to clean it.

Comment: I tried that one out now. 
The log don't give me any value. Its like id is a empty string

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

**I think it is a problem of dom structure so try to surround your html by table tag .**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
       var id = 1;

       function updateMsg() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/opt/history/update?current=" + 1,
       cache: false,
       success: function(html){
          var html1= "<table>"+html+" </table>";
         var jqObj=$('<div>',{html:html1});   /// here is the trick   
            id = jqObj.find('#last').html();
            console.log('ID: ' + id);
            $("#result").html(html);
       }
    });
setTimeout(updateMsg, 5000);
}

updateMsg();
         });
```

Comment: The log tells me that id is undefined when i try this one out

Comment: @Jemil Riahi I tried it and it works perfect ! please console.log(html) and let me see it

Comment: I have console.log(html) above.